# Error while converting String to DateTime: String cannot be type of DateTime

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime

I get data from an API and the date comes in String value. I am converting String data to DateTime and trying to format it.

The problem is that the incoming data never comes as null. If it is null it comes as "N/A" and therefore gives an error. I think it gave an error while parsing because the data came in N/A form.

Data that didn't come in "N/A" format was perfectly formatted.

```
String endDate = "N/A";
    if (data.endDate != null) {
      var endDateTime = DateTime.parse(data.endDate!);
      endDate = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(endDateTime);
    }
```

Is there a way to format the data or should I give up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use [`DateTime.tryParse`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/DateTime/tryParse.html) and check if the result is `null` to indicate that parsing failed.

```dart
var endDateTime = DateTime.tryParse(data.endDate ?? '');
var endDate = (endDateTime == null)
    ? "N/A"
    : DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(endDateTime);
```

Note that the above would use `"N/A"` for *any* parsing failure.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?:

```
var endDateTime = DateTime.parse(data.endDate!);

String endDate = (!data.endData || data.endData === 'N/A') ? 'N/A' : DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(endDateTime)
```

Let me know.

Comment: Can you past a response example in both cases when is null e when return a date please? Thanks

Comment: I Solved the Problem mate but if the "N/A" data changes it will crash the app

Answer (score 0):

Solution

```
 String endDate = "N/A";
    if (data.endDate!.length > 3) {
      var endDateTime = DateTime.parse(data.endDate!);
      endDate = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(endDateTime);
    }
```